# Lógica para curva ABC

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e gostaria de fazer uma página apenas para dados estatísticos, um desses dados é a Curva ABC de clientes, ou seja, quero retornar os clientes que mais compram. Eu estou faz dias tentando pensar em uma lógica para resolver isso mas não consigo nada que não seja "gambiarra".

Bom, o sistema está assim: o operador finaliza a venda e se está anexado algum cliente, o sistema grava seu ID. No banco de dados a tabela de vendas possui a coluna "client_id".

A ideia é fazer um SELECT para percorrer essa tabela e ir contando quantas vendas determinado cliente tem. O problema é que não consigo pensar em nada para resolver isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua consulta SQL vai precisar de uma função de agrupamento, e vai ficar como algo assim:

```
//seleciono os campos que necessito (nome e quantidade) da tabela de vendas
SELECT client_name, count(client_id) 'Qtde vendas' FROM vendas
//relaciono com a tabela de clientes para recuperar o nome do cliente
INNER JOIN clientes ON id = client_id
//especifico que quero os resultados agrupados pelo nome do cliente 
GROUP BY client_name
//e ordeno do maior para o maior
ORDER BY count(client_id) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu select ficaria assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(v.id) as qtd_vendas, v.client_id as id_cliente, c.nome as cliente
FROM tb_vendas v
  LEFT JOIN tb_cliente c ON c.id = v.client_id
GROUP BY id_cliente, cliente
ORDER BY qtd_vendas DESC;
```

A partir do momento que você renomeia uma coluna com o **AS** você pode colocar no **GROUP BY** e **ORDER BY** somente os apelidos. 
Coloquei esse outro somando o valor das vendas por cliente também (levando em conta que para cada venda temos o valor da mesma) e ordenando pelo valor máximo da venda, que fica assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(v.id) AS qtd_vendas,
       SUM(v.valor_venda) AS valor_venda,
       v.client_id as id_cliente, c.nome as cliente
FROM tb_vendas v
  LEFT JOIN tb_cliente c ON c.id = v.client_id
GROUP BY id_cliente, cliente
ORDER BY qtd_vendas DESC;
```

Explicando este último select:

- **COUNT** irá contar a quantidade de vendas realizadas por cliente;
- **SUM** é para somar o valor das vendas e apresentar por cliente.
- **LEFT JOIN** porque você quer frisar a quantidade de vendas por cliente ou seja a prioridade é de *clientes mas que estejam na tabela de vendas*.
- **GROUP BY** agrupa as informações por cliente e como coloquei o nome do cliente, também precisa informar este campo no group by.
- **ORDER BY** valor_pago **DESC**, ordena o resultado pelo valor máximo de compras feitas para a menor quantidade de compras feitas por cliente, já te mostrando qual cliente comprou o mais (lembrando que aqui teria o valor de qual cliente comprou mais vezes, se você quiser o cliente que teve o maior valor em reais de compras é só trocar para ordenar pelo campo valor_venda).